# PowerPoint- Print 11x17 Default for any user on any location

Tags: ms-office, powerpoint

I have already used the Design-Custom Size to Set each of my slides up as 11x17. But I have an executive asking if I can "Have it so when the push ctrl+p it automatically prints the slides as 11x17 and of possible just 2 slides in the deck like this and the rest normal" I understand that as the user you have to select printer properties prior to printing to print out as 11x17. Keep in mind they may even be using a different printer.. Is there a way to just hardcode the .ppt slide to communicate to the printer to print 11x17

Answer (score 0):

What you want isn't possible, unfortunately.  A custom-written add-in could add a new button on the ribbon that'd cause PPT to print in a particular way, though.